# Perl, using Mechanize-Firefox, how can I expand a frame whilst remaining within the larger frameset.

Tags: html, perl, firefox, mechanize, frames

I'm scraping a website that uses frames extensively. Within each frame is a piece of javascript like so:

```
function CheckUniqName(uniq) {
if (top.name != uniq) {
top.window.location.assign("<a webpage I don't want to redirect to>");
return false;
}
return true;
}
CheckUniqName("#unique_string#")
```

If I open one of these frames using $mech->follow_link(name=>'FrameName') then I get instantly redirected to "a webpage I don't want to redirect to". Turning JavaScript "off" prevents the redirect (obviously), but I need the JavaScript "on" in order to complete certain actions on the page.

I've got a few ideas for how to make this work, but I don't know how to implement them:

(1) Expand the frames rather than follow them as links. If I expand the frames but remain within the larger frameset then top.name will equal uniq and it won't redirect (because the name of the topmost window is "#unique_string#"). How can do this? I don't understand how $mech->expand_frames works.

(2) Disable these lines of JS. Is it possible in Mechanize to force the program to ignore certain lines of content? If Mechanize would just ignore the line "top.window.location.assign("");" then it wouldn't redirect. Is that possible to do?

(3) Change the value of the variable top.name. If I could reassign top.name to equal #unique_string# then I could pass the check regardless of what the window name is. Would that be possible? I think the server defines the window name.

Any help from stack would be hugely appreciated. This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use greasemonkey plugin to remove this piece of JS from the page before its gets loaded?

Regards,